# How to define launch screen storyboard image size in universal application in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, launch-screen

I had a  universal iPhone application in which i am decided to use
 launch screen storyboard instead of launch images.

Now i added a full screen image view on to it then i need an image of size 1x,2x,3x to fill that image view.

i am very much confused about the size of the image i need to add in
 assets.was it like 600*600(1x),2x,3x according to it .

but on that case image is showing as stretched,Can anybody help me on
 this ?

Comment: you have to add all the images of all dimensions under launch screen options

Comment: @Abhi if i am not mistaken launch screen storyboard is introduced to simplify that process

Comment: Check this one https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html, you can use `autolayout` in that `xib` file to fit many devices.

Answer (score 2):

you can put all size images in `assets`. add new image set in it and select `attribute inspector` and check `iphone` and `ipad` from checkbox and `uncheck` universal. so you are able to put images for iphone and ipad both separately. Hope this will help :)